# Scala fallback with Futures and return value instead of future

Tags: scala, future, fallback

So here is the situation

I have a function

```
def funcA(): Future[Map[String,String]] // Lets say Future1
def funcB(): Future[Map[String,String]] // Lets say Future2
```

So what I want to do is to define another function such that
        //Need to make some change in this function

```
 def funcCombine(): Future[Map[String,String]] = {
     for{
       a <- funcA()
       b <- funcB() if a.isEmpty
     }
}
```

Check value of map from FuncA and if its not empty return it else check for map in FuncB and return the map if not empty otherwise return empty map.

How can I do this fallback kind of mechanism. 
I tried to solve this myself but could not really come out with anything.

Comment: There is `Future.find(List(f1,f2,Future.successful(default))(result => isgood(result))`.

Comment: @jwvh Here you are checking for both a and b, whereas I would want to execute b only if ma result empty.  Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: If the `b` thread has not been launched yet then the received parameter is not type `Future[...]`.

Comment: That's `recoverWith`, to handle success and failure cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think `flatMap` is going to be your friend here.

```
funcA().flatMap(m => if (m.isEmpty) funcB() else Future.successful(m))
```

Comment: Why cant we use map instead of flatmap. Sorry I am new to scala and I dont see why flatmap works and not map

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal; It's because `funcB()` returns a new `Future`. If you use `map()` instead then the result type would be `Future[Future[Map[...]]]`. `flatMap()` "flattens" the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
def funcCombine(): Future[Map[String,String]] = {
 Future.find(List(funcA(),funcB()))(mapp => mapp.nonEmpty).map{
            case Some(mapp) => mapp
            case None => Map.empty
          }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.